# Detecting zero in solution of linear system of equations (Ax=b)

Tags: r, floating-point, equation-solving, rounding-error

Suppose the following system of equations `Ax = b` with:

```
> A <- matrix(c(2,0,-1,0,0,2,2,1,-1,2,0,0,0,1,0,0), ncol = 4)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    0   -1    0
[2,]    0    2    2    1
[3,]   -1    2    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0

> b <- c(-2,5,0,0)
```

Solving these equations with `solve()` yields:

```
> x <- solve(A,b)
> x
[1] 6.66e-16 4.44e-16 2.00e+00 1.00e+00
```

This is just an example, but `A` and `b` can be of any form.

I need to detect whether any component of `x` is 0. Now, the first two components should actually be 0, but they are both higher than the machine epsilon `.Machine$double.eps = 2.22e-16` which makes them very small, but not equal to zero.

I think I understand that this is caused by rounding errors in floating point arithmetic inside `solve()`. What I need to know is whether it is possible (from a practical point of view) to determine the higher bound of these errors, so 0s can be detected. For example, instead of

```
> x == 0
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

one would use something like this:

```
> x > -1e-15 & x < 1e-15
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Giving more insight into this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: can't you just use `round()` ?

Comment: Up to what decimal? I could use so many quick & dirty things, but before I use any, I would like some (statistical) justification for it. So this question might have many answers, one better than the other... You can certainly start with that one :)

Comment: Did someone say statistics? If that's the case, then think about what you would consider zero. Anything below/above that is effectively zero.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, my own 'statistical - misnomer here' approach was under assumption of `A %*% x == b` to calculate the worst case boundaries of `x`. If 0 falls within, then it is 0. Problem is that in this case `A %*% x == b` yields `[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`, and thus can not be relied upon... That is why I was hoping someone could shed more light into workings of `solve()` and what the reasonable assumptions could be.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is to check if we can find a better solution to the linear system if we assume the components to be zero. For that we would want to solve `A[3:4]%*%y=b` since `A%*%c(0,0,x[3],x[4])=A[3:4]%*%c(x[3],x[4])`. This is an overdetermined system so we can't use `solve` to find a solution. We can however use `qr.solve`:

```
> x.new = c(0,0,qr.solve(A[,3:4],b))
```

It remains to check if this solution is really better:

```
> norm(A%*%x.new - b) < norm(A%*%x - b)
[1] TRUE
```

Thus we have a good reason to suspect that `x[1]==x[2]==0`.

---

In this simple example it is obviously possible to guess the true solution by looking at the approximate solution:

```
> x.true = c(0,0,2,1)
> norm(A%*%x.true - b)
[1] 0
```

This is however not very helpful in the general case.